# there are 2 numbers in $(n+1)<2n$ numbers that prime to each other

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that if we have $n+1$ numbers from positive integers that each of them less than $2n$ there are 2 numbers in this $n+1$ numbers that prime to each other.

Comment: Bertrand's postulate might help here.

Comment: Easier: consecutive numbers are always coprime.

Comment: So in fact it's enough that the numbers be $\le 2n$.

Comment: Side comment: I believe this is what Paul Erdos asked one of his young students, forgot his students name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $A$ $=$ {$1,2,...,2n$}$B$ $=${$1,3,...2n-1$} and $C$ $=$ {$2,4,...,2n$}.we know that $|B|=n$ and $|C|=n$
so for all sets for example $C$ that $C⊆A$ and $|C|$=$n+1$ according to Pigeonhole principle there are 2 consecutive numbers and we know that they are coprime.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the chosen numbers must be pairwise different (otherwise the statement is false), put the numbers in an increasing sequence
$$a_1<\ldots<a_{n+1}$$

Suposse that
$$m:=\min_{1\le k\le n}(a_{k+1}-a_k)\ge2$$

Then $a_{n+1}\ge a_1+2n>2n$, a contradiction. Thus, $m=1$, that is, there are two consecutive numbers between the chosen ones, and these two are coprime.